# Как заархивировать каждую папку в директории в отдельный архив .zip на python

Tags: python, zip, архивация

Например есть директория D:\test\flo в которой 3 папки Test4, Test67, Test8. (в каждой папке тоже есть файлы)

В итоге надо получить в директории D:\test\zip файлы Test4.zip, Test67.zip, Test8.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно вот так.

```
import glob
import os
import zipfile

scan_path = 'D:\test\flo'
dest_path = 'D:\test\zip'

for directory in os.scandir(scan_path):
    if directory.is_dir():
        with zipfile.ZipFile(f'{dest_path}\\{directory.name}.zip', 'w') as f:
            for file in glob.glob(f'{directory.path}/*'):
                f.write(file)
```